# Does dark matter act gravitationaly to itself. If Yes, why does not form more compact objects?

Tags: energy, gravity, dark-matter

Does dark matter act gravitationaly to itself.If Yes, why does not form more compact objects? Can this be explained as its components have enough kinetic energy to overcome the collapse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If dark matter only interacts with gravity, why doesn't it all clump together in a single point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214950/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dark matter acts on itself via gravity, why wouldn't it. It can't form compact objects because it can't shed angular momentum, as explained here: [If dark matter only interacts with gravity, why doesn't it all clump together in a single point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214950/if-dark-matter-only-interacts-with-gravity-why-doesnt-it-all-clump-together-in)

Comment: Shouldn't it be able to shed angular momentum via gravitational waves?

Comment: Yes but that's utterly negligible. The dominant effect comes from three-body interactions ("swing-by") and even that is very inefficient