# Why doesn't the lack of electromagnetic repulsion between dark matter particles result in the formation of black holes?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, gravity, astrophysics, dark-matter

From what I've researched dark matter isn't subject to electromagnetic forces, which I'm assuming implies that there is a lack of electromagnetic repulsion between dark matter particles.

If there's nothing to repel them, then shouldn't they clump up together and form a black hole?

Comment: Why *should* they clump? Consider conservation of energy, as applied to gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214950/180843